# Resizing on click and returning to original position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/fFs4B/

This is driving me up the wall. I want any `div` that is clicked to expand to the container size, and then to shrink back down to size. And that last part is making me scream profanities. Help?

```
var margLeft = '0%';
var margTop = '0%';
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('.container div').click(function() {        
        if ($(this).hasClass('wide')) {
            margLeft = '0%';
            margTop = '0%';

            var clickedElem = $(this);
            clickedElem.removeClass('wide');
            deflateThis(clickedElem);
        }
        else {
            var clickedElem = $(this);
            inflateThis(clickedElem);
        }
    });
});

function inflateThis(clickedElem) {
    clickedElem.siblings().fadeOut(500, function() {   
        $('p').append(clickedElem.css('left'));
        if (clickedElem.css('left') !== '0%') {
            margLeft = '-50%';   
        }
        if (clickedElem.css('top') !== '0%') {
            margTop = '-50%';
        }
        clickedElem.animate({
            'left': '0',
            'top': '0',
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '100%'
        }, function() {
            clickedElem.addClass('wide');               
        });
    });   
}

function deflateThis(clickedElem) {
    if (margLeft == '0%') {
        margLeft = '0%';
    }
    else {
        margLeft = '50%';
    }
    if (margTop == '0%') {
        margTop = '0%';
    }
    else {
        margTop = '50%';
    }
    clickedElem.animate({
        'left': margLeft,
        'top': margTop,
        'width': '50%',
        'height': '50%'
    }, function() {
        clickedElem.siblings().fadeIn(500);       
    });   
}
```

Comment: try keeping tabs on original position via a `data-` attribute or class  so you know if you should re-position to bottom/right versus top/left.

Comment: When you fetch the current "left" or "top" values, they're reported in pixels, not percentages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with keeping track of the left and top offset values.

Here is one way of fixing it:

```
var margLeft = '';
var margTop = '';

$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('.container div').click(function() {        
        if ($(this).hasClass('wide')) {
            var clickedElem = $(this);
            clickedElem.removeClass('wide');
            deflateThis(clickedElem);
        }
        else {
            var clickedElem = $(this);
            inflateThis(clickedElem);
        }
    });
});

function inflateThis(clickedElem) {
    margLeft = clickedElem.css('left');
    margTop = clickedElem.css('top');
    clickedElem.siblings().fadeOut(500, function() {   
        clickedElem.animate({
            'left': '0px',
            'top': '0px',
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '100%'
        }, function() {
            clickedElem.addClass('wide');               
        });
    });   
}

function deflateThis(clickedElem) {
    clickedElem.animate({
        'left': margLeft,
        'top': margTop,
        'width': '50%',
        'height': '50%'
    }, function() {
        clickedElem.removeClass('wide'); 
        clickedElem.siblings().fadeIn(500);       
    });   
}
```

When you inflate the element, save the left and top offsets in the native pixel values.

When you deflate, restore them from the global variables and also remove the `.wide` class from the element that was deflated.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/yhDjt/

**Comment**

I think you meant the color panels to be sized and positioned with respect to the `.container`, so I added `position: relative` to the CSS rule.

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/fFs4B/5/

```
$('.container div').click(function() { 
    $('.container div').toggleClass('hide'); //hides all divs
    $(this).toggleClass('hide'); //unhide this div
    $(this).toggleClass('wide'); //wide this div
});
```

Leave the styles in the Css.

Comment: But not quite the effect I wanted! I know how easy and simple this is in CSS3, but I want the elements to DISAPPEAR first, and I certainly don't want to use CSS3 because I am designing this specifically for outdated versions of browsers. Thanks though!